# How to access Django models outside of Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to access my Django models from a script that will be run outside of any Django views. It will be a standalone script and not related to any Django views etc, however, I would like to be able to use the Django ORM to update fields in the database.

My standalone script is in the data directory:

[image]

I have tried endless suggestions from SO, such as the code below, but I keep hitting a similar issue - "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nft.settings'"

```
import django
import sys
import os
sys.path.append('/Users/chris/Documents/Python/Django/nft/')  # This path being the directory at the top of my screenshot
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "nft.settings")
django.setup()
from nft_app.models import Object
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you run this script?

Comment: "python script.py"

Comment: What directory are you in when you run that?

Comment: the "data" directory

Comment: Why not use a custom management command? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that python looks for packages in the current directory and the PATH. Since you run `python script.py` in the `nft/data` directory, it looks for `nft/data/nft` for the `nft` package.

One solution to this is to add `nft/nft` directory to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I've actually just moved my script to the root directory and it seems to have done the trick. Thank you so much!